# write if/else condition for mail merge template

Tags: mail-merge, merge

Does anyone have an example of an If statement in a microsoft word mail merge template? I would like to use salutation on some of my labels but not all records have data so salesforce replaces it with eight underscores (no clue why). I'd like to replace those underscores with an if statement but Im having trouble figuring out the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Fourq,

Historically, we have solved this in one of two ways:

1. Replace your word templates with VisualForce Templates, in which case JimRae's comment is applicable.
2. Creative and judicious use of Formula fields. Using this method, you'll be merging in your formula field, not the actual contact_salutation field. Essentially, your Formula field, say fContactSalutation__c uses

   IF(isEmpty(contact_salutation), 'replacement text', contact_salutation)

Comment: Great idea. I'm going to try #2 today. Thank you. I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would use something like this:

```
{ IF { MERGEFIELD salutation  } = "" { MERGEFIELD "" } { MERGEFIELD salutation } }
```

Just replace the "salutation" with the field you are merging.

Comment: I'm going to try this within the hour. I'll get back to you it right away!

Comment: I tried that and I also tried: { IF { MERGEFIELD Contact_Salutation } = "________" "Nope" {MERGEFIELD Contact_Salutaion} \ * MERGEFORMAT } but neither work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible to have conditional IF statements in an email template.
Some time its not works when you are using "HTML Email Template"  because of metadata issue.
Issue:
If you are using IF statements in HTML email template, some time its metadat in backend add some formating html and css inside of IF statements, Thats why its not working.

Solution:
Edit the email template matadata and remove all html and css which is inside of IF statement:

[image]

After removing all these strange and useless html, Save it. 
Now this will work for you :)